# How do i set up mod_mono on 11.10?

Tags: server, apache2, mono

I have a Amazon Web Services Server with Ubuntu 11.10 installed I have insalled mono and i have successfully dployed ad launched a .NET webservice with xsp4. Now I want to host it on that server. I am trying to figure out how to set up Apache and mod_mono to use. I was told Apache is already installed by default. But I don't know where to find it. I am a complete Newbie with Linux!! 
Help Please!

Comment: well I installed apache2 "sudo apt-get install apache2"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is probably what you want.

```
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-mono mono-apache-server2
```

Here are some informative links that should help you get started.

- [Official mod_mono Tutorial](http://mono-project.com/Mod_mono)
- [Ubuntu's Official mod_mono Tutorial](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ModMono)
- [Nice write-up on setting up a Ubuntu machine with Apache, MySQL, and Mono](http://www.toptensoftware.com/Articles/6/Setting-up-a-Ubuntu-Apache-MySQL-Mono-ASP-NET-MVC-2-Development-Server)

If you're only searching for which package to install, try the following command:

```
sudo apt-cache search keyword-here
```

So for instance,

```
sudo apt-cache search mod_mono
```

Gives this:

```
asp.net-examples - demo pages for ASP.NET infrastructure
libapache2-mod-mono - Apache module for running ASP.NET applications on Mono
mono-apache-server - ASP.NET backend for mod_mono Apache module - default version
mono-apache-server2 - ASP.NET 2.0 backend for mod_mono2 Apache module
mono-apache-server4 - ASP.NET 1.1 backend for mod_mono Apache module
```

The first package mentioned is not necessarily relevant, but the other lines tell you which packages have something to do with mod_mono, and what they do exactly.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, Before you responded I ran the command: sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-mono. It went through and did what it needed. but now for the last hour I don't know what to do. it just said: Setting up mono-apache-server4 (2.10-1) ...
 * Reloading web server config apache2                                   [ OK ] 
 * Restarting web server apache2                                                 ... waiting .                                                           [ OK ]

Comment: Yeah, I think it did that to me too (I did this a while back, memory's a bit foggy). I think i had opened a second terminal and issued the command `sudo service apache2 reload; sudo service apache2 restart` and apt had moved on after.. I *think*.

Comment: I'm almost there the apache seems to work and the folder is set up. I Deployed a asmx webservice and I try rowsing to it : http://xx.xxx.xxx.xxx/EmailChecker/CheckEmailAddress.asmx. and instead of showing me the web service. It downloaded the asmx file. how to I set it to be an page?

Comment: Ah! We're getting there :) This seems to be a problem with MIME types perhaps? What does `ls /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/*mod_mono*` say? Also, check out the post found [here](http://serverfault.com/a/129860/110670) and see if it helps.

Comment: -bash: /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/mod_mono.conf: Permission denied

Comment: You missed the `ls` in front! :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3407/discussion-between-sircharlo-and-greektreat)

Comment: Very nice tip, SirCharlo.